# framer motion : different animation for mobile and desktop

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, framer-motion

Trying to make a different animation when on mobile or on desktop, to do so I'm using a useMediaQueryHoook and changing the variant in function of it. But the init animation seems to always assume that I'm on desktop. I guess because the useMediaQueryHook doesn't have time to actualise before the anim is launch. How can I deal with that issue ?

Btw I'm on nextjs :)

Here is my code :

```
  const onMobile = useMediaQuery("(min-width : 428px)");

  const wishCardVariant = {
    hidden: (onMobile) => ({
      opacity: 0,
      y: onMobile ? "100%" : 0,
      x: onMobile ? 0 : "100%",
      transition,
    }),
    visible: (onMobile) => ({
      opacity: 1,
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
    }),
  };
```

here is the hook :

```
import react, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function useMediaQuery(query) {
  const [matches, setMatches] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const media = window.matchMedia(query);
    if (media.matches !== matches) {
      setMatches(media.matches);
    }
    const listener = () => {
      setMatches(media.matches);
    };
    media.addListener(listener);
    return () => media.removeListener(listener);
  }, [matches, query]);

  return matches;
}
```

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using useLayoutEffect. I had a similar issue, where I wanted to apply a different style based on device type, and this worked for me

```
export default function useMediaQuery(query: string) {
  const [matches, setMatches] = useState(false)

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    const media = window.matchMedia(query)
    if (media.matches !== matches) {
      setMatches(media.matches)
    }
    const listener = () => {
      setMatches(media.matches)
    }
    media.addEventListener('change', listener)
    return () => media.removeEventListener('change', listener)
  }, [matches, query])

  return matches
}
```